# Android : activity is displayed?

Tags: android, android-activity, focus

In my android application i would like to know if an activty is displayed or not ? How can I do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your activity is in the foreground and the user has focus, the system invokes `Activity.onResume()` and when your activity is completely obscured `Activity.onStop()` is invoked so between the two methods you can determine if your activity is visible with focus.

Comment: Than is not a method for to this...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the basics here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

The activity will Pause when it goes to the background and it will "resume" when it comes back to top. So by `onResume()` method you can catch it.